# Path bar High Sierra doesn't work with search results on SMB fileserver

Tags: high-sierra, search, file, smb, path

Yosemite
[image: Yosemite]

High Sierra
[image]

Hi there!

At our Prepress department I’ve updated some iMacs from Yosemite to High Sierra.
When I search in Yosemite on the SMB fileserver for a specific file, I see after a while the search results in the Finder window. If I select a found file I see the full path in the Path bar at the bottom of this Finder window. (See the first screenshot.)

But when I do the exact same search command in High Sierra on this SMB fileserver, I see the same search results. But when I select a found file in these search results, I don’t see the file path. In stead of that I see only the icon of the file. (See the second screenshot.) Also the found files are showing blank file icons.

When I perform in High Sierra a search command on the internal drive or a USB stick the full path of the found file is visible.

I guess the absence of the file path in High Sierra has something to do with the SMB protocol.
Apple has discarded the AFP protocol in High Sierra and uses SMB instead. Yosemite still uses AFP so i guess thats why the full file path is showing.

My question: is it possible to make the full file path visible again in High Sierra when selecting a file in the search results on a SMB server?

Comment: When you have found a file on the SMB share is the Hide/Show Path Bar greyed out or not? You may be right, also it *might* have something to do with the filesystem on the target there (guessing...) If it is greyed out but says "Hide path bar" you may be right.

Comment: I can't provide an answer, because I can't quite figure what's going on :/ but I **do** see the path bar on SMB shares. As Steve hints, the show/hide Pathbar option in View menu is greyed out - so in my case I can't switch it off.

Comment: When I make a search command on the SMB fileserver the Hide/Show Path Bar is greyed out.
I guess it has nothing to do with the file system on the server because the Path bar works great in Yosemite.

Comment: The file server is a Linux based system.

Comment: After the install of update 10.13.4 the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Either this was a bug that is fixed in 10.13.4 or the upgrade and restart has fixed this.

If you can run a reinstall of your OS in cases like this, it might help.